# How to parallel test execute with Robot framework?

Tags: robotframework

I want to know how I can execute two different test case at same time.In first test case I will do regular things and I want to get value from variables in second test case while first test executing.

Any help would be good for me.

I search and find pabot library,subprocess and test template.But I did not found any good example or topic to help me.Also I cannot install pabot library. I get error "conda.exceptions.ResolvePackageNotFound:

- robotframework-pabot".
  I have to install packages via conda_environment.yml. I already install another packages but I cannot install pabot.

Comment: robotframework mainly releases to pypi repository and thus its  installable via  `pip`. Installation instructions are  @ https://github.com/mkorpela/pabot#installation=

Answer (score 0):

You can install the pabot library from the command prompt using the below command,

> pip install -U robotframework-pabot

And also u can install it from the PyCharm settings (if you use PyCharm) as below,

> File --> Settings --> Project --> python interpreter --> Click on the
> "+" icon --> Search for robotfrmaework-pabot --> Install it